# Can not get previous tr input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Little bit confession about get value of previous table tr checkbox checked.

I want to get value of previous tr input value but it's always return next tr value. We are checking checkbox on other element change event.

My code is the following:

```js
/*
Here i want to get value of tr instead of click because 
we have many conditions and I can't explain them all here 
*/
$('body').on('change', '.change_product_price', function() {
  var test1 = $(this).parent().parent().closest('tr').find('.chkIt').val();
  console.log(test1)
});

$('.chkIt').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.change_product_price').val('1');
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.change_product_price').change();
  } else {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.change_product_price').val('0');
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.change_product_price').change();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="product_row">
    <td class="small-check SerialNumber"><input class="chkIt" type="checkbox" name="products[product_id][]" value="76" qty="0" product_weight="0"></td>
    <td data-th="Product Name" class="fourth_i1">8 PACK SPECIALIST EMBOSSED SILVER FOIL 500 SHEET BOX 12CM X 20CM</td>
    <td data-th="Part Number" class="grid-text">EMBOSS-Pre-Cut x 8 Pack</td>
    <td class="small-check MarkGift"><input class="chkItg" type="checkbox" name="gift[product_id][]" value="78"></td>
    <td data-th="Quantity" class="grid-text">
      <select name="products[quantity][78][]" class="change_product_price">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" class="promo_min_quantity" name="promo_min_quantity" value="">
      <input type="hidden" class="promo_free_units" name="promo_free_units" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="product_row">
    <td class="small-check SerialNumber"><input class="chkIt" type="checkbox" name="products[product_id][]" value="78" qty="0" product_weight="0"></td>
    <td data-th="Product Name" class="fourth_i1">8 PACK SPECIALIST EMBOSSED SILVER FOIL 500 SHEET BOX 12CM X 20CM</td>
    <td data-th="Part Number" class="grid-text">EMBOSS-Pre-Cut x 8 Pack</td>
    <td class="small-check MarkGift"><input class="chkItg" type="checkbox" name="gift[product_id][]" value="78"></td>
    <td data-th="Quantity" class="grid-text">
      <select name="products[quantity][78][]" class="change_product_price">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" class="promo_min_quantity" name="promo_min_quantity" value="">
      <input type="hidden" class="promo_free_units" name="promo_free_units" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="product_row">
    <td class="small-check SerialNumber"><input class="chkIt" type="checkbox" name="products[product_id][]" value="125" qty="0" product_weight="0"></td>
    <td data-th="Product Name" class="fourth_i1">8 PACK SPECIALIST EMBOSSED SILVER FOIL 500 SHEET BOX 12CM X 20CM</td>
    <td data-th="Part Number" class="grid-text">EMBOSS-Pre-Cut x 8 Pack</td>
    <td class="small-check MarkGift"><input class="chkItg" type="checkbox" name="gift[product_id][]" value="125"></td>
    <td data-th="Quantity" class="grid-text">
      <select name="products[quantity][125][]" class="change_product_price">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" class="promo_min_quantity" name="promo_min_quantity" value="">
      <input type="hidden" class="promo_free_units" name="promo_free_units" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]
Here there are 3 values of each tr input `76, 78 and 125` currently my checkboxed

Problem is i have checked last $227.60 checkbox but it's return value of $174.40

Comment: Too many `parent` calls, `closest` will directly find the element you are looking for. Try just `$(this).closest('tr').find('.chkIt').val();`

Comment: create a hidden form field name as previous_checked set value into hidden_field on check , checkbox. and retrieve its value on next click on checkbox.

Comment: @msg Unless i'm misreading, their selector should be fine, albeit a little ugly.  The first parent is the `<td>`, the second is the `<tr>`, and `.closest()` looks for the nearest traversing upwards [**starting with itself**](https://jsfiddle.net/gj54yr7t/) - so I believe it would just return the same `<tr>`. Although I still prefer `.closest()` over using `.parent()` at all as you've suggested.

Comment: I've edited your question to include a full, runnable snippet. It seems to be working fine.

Comment: @TylerRoper yep, you're right, `closest` begins with the element itself, `parents` with the first ancestor.

Comment: "get value of *previous tr input value* but it's always return next tr value". Can you clarify this ? You want to get the value "303.60" in your image ?

Comment: @msg I want to get value $227.60 when i click checkbox but it's  return next tr value $174.40 instead of  $227.60

Comment: @SamirSheikh The code you've provided doesn't have any "click checkbox" functionality; it fires on the change of the *quantity dropdown*, and it works fine. Perhaps you shared the wrong JavaScript snippet?

Comment: If you find yourself using the same query a lot, just assign it to a variable.  It will still be there unless it is removed from the dom.